# Are there general guidelines for including code in a research paper?

Tags: writing-style, code

I'm a beginning researcher trying to write a research paper , so please bear with some of the really basic questions I might have. I've already looked around for some help online, but the websites I found were vague.

My program is written in perl. Should I include my code in the paper? If so, is there a maximum number of lines? Will people expect me to include all of it in the paper (either in the appendix or in the body) or can I just write out in text the general idea of what it does?

Comment: You haven't said what this paper is for (e.g. planning to publish it in a journal? Honors thesis for school? Something else?) - please [edit] your post to clarify this detail.

Comment: Also, the StackExchange way is [one question per post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1204/11365) so I've removed the secondary question about whether to use LaTeX - which has already [been covered pretty thoroughly here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5414/what-are-the-advantages-or-disadvantages-of-using-latex-for-writing-scientific-p).

Comment: Related: [How much code to include in a physics paper?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10629/how-much-code-to-include-in-a-physics-paper)

Comment: Related: [Including many pages of serialization code and generated source code in Master's thesis?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23851/including-many-pages-of-serialization-code-and-generated-source-code-in-masters)

Comment: @user22319: take into account that nowadays many journals allow you to publish additional material online. If the journal where you intend to publish provides this service, you might describe short code snippets in the article and upload the complete source code as online material.

Comment: Related [How to share computer code?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16785/). This might be a borderline dupe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, I would **never** include code in the "main" paper outside of computer science or applied mathematics. There are very few cases where listing code explicitly would actually improve the quality and readability of the paper. If it is necessary to include the code, I would do so as part of the "Supporting Information" which many journals allow you to include alongside the main publication. I would then describe the features of the code as words in the main text.

Even in CS and math papers, I would still only put *pseudocode* in the main article, and would save any listings of actual code for the Supporting Information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have been writing papers for nearly a decade. And I have never seen anyone including source code in any publication (except in dissertations). Everyone prefers to include a well defined algorithm section in the paper. I think there would/could be two (or more) reasons behind this:

1. The (main and related) codes are lengthy and take a lot of space in your paper that could otherwise be used for something else.
2. Everyone who would read your paper might not very good at programming in the language you chose. For instance, maybe I include an FFT script in MATLAB, and it is possible the readers are more interested to see it in Python or C etc. So, in this case adding a code would not add a lot of value in your paper. Therefore, I normally say that the pseudocode language is more universal.

Answer (score 0):

The norms and expectations for including code as supporting information vary across fields.

Personally, I would include your code as a supporting information. This allows others to recreate your work.
See resources and references I cited in an [answer to a previous question on a similar topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/118511/33210).